# systemd service is writing a file as root, process runs as ubuntu

Tags: systemd

I have the following service file:

```
[Unit]
Description=P
Requires=network.target
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
Restart=always
RestartSec=1
TimeoutStartSec=1s
WorkingDirectory=/home/ubuntu/R/bp/
ExecStart=/usr/bin/node server.js
User=ubuntu
StandardOutput=file:/home/ubuntu/R/bp/p.out
StandardError=file:/home/ubuntu/R/bp/p.out

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

When I start the service it runs as ubuntu.

However the file it writes is owned by root.

```
-rw-r--r--  1 root   root      9217 Mar  5 16:14 p.out
```

I want the file to be owned by ubuntu user.

My version of ubuntu is 18.04.3

Comment: Why does it matter? It's readable by you, and will be re-written every time the service runs anyway.

Comment: When I start the service initially, the file is created and written to, however when I restart the service or stop/start the service, the service is started but the file remains as is. I'm thinking that might be because the file is owned by root.... So basically I am finding the file is not rewritten every time the service runs.

Comment: Hmmm. Consider about THAT question then. File ownership seems an irrelevant rabbit-hole, not the real problem.

Comment: I'd kind of like it to be owned by ubuntu as well.

Answer (score 2):

I got it to do what I want by adding these lines to the service file. Probably this is not a good solution, but I just really needed to get this working.

```
ExecStartPre=/bin/rm -fr /home/ubuntu/R/bp/p.out
ExecStartPost=/usr/bin/sudo /bin/chown ubuntu:ubuntu /home/ubuntu/R/bp/p.out
```

Answer (score 0):

I would make it in another way. Your service should run as your normal user?

Place you systemd.service  in /etc/systemd/user/

Then you can enable it with

```
systemctl --user enable your.service
```

Then you can spare these parts.

```
ExecStartPre=/bin/rm -fr /home/ubuntu/R/bp/p.out
ExecStartPost=/usr/bin/sudo /bin/chown ubuntu:ubuntu /home/ubuntu/R/bp/p.out
```